# Discord Bot in Python raises Error Channel

Tags: python, discord

Im not sure how to send a message to specific discord channel using interactions.py

embeds1[1] is equal to an embed message and its not an issue the issie is with channel it can't find key word called channel
await ctx.send(channel=1096927294087516322, embeds=embeds1[1])

Comment: **im using interactions.py means im using bot = interactions.Client(...)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`ComponentContext.send`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context.html#interactions.client.context.ComponentContext.send) documentation, it does not have a `channel` parameter. Instead, you have to call the [`Channel.send`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.models.channel.html#interactions.api.models.channel.Channel.send) method directly on the desired [`Channel`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.models.channel.html), by using [`utilities.get.get`](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.get.html#interactions.utils.get.get) to retrieve a channel from its id.

What you should be doing is:

```py
import interactions
from interactions.utils.get import get

# Your client
bot = interactions.Client()

# Get channel from its id
channel = await get(bot, interactions.Channel, object_id=1096927294087516322)

# Send the embed in the desired channel
await channel.send(embeds=[embeds1[1]])
```

Comment: im using interactions.py means im using bot = interactions.Client(...)